# PHP array with mysql and other

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have table1 with phone numbers with data like 09454151,094949154 and other data about client.

My input data was in phone number like: 000385926555494 or 0385981961969
that i convert to: 0926555494 or 0981961969

That works fine with code (where $broj00 = '000385926555494 '):

```
$broj00 = preg_replace('/'.ULAZNI_POZIV.'/', '', $broj);
//dodavanje prefixa za ljepsi pregeld broja
$prfix = 0;
$broj01 = array($prefix,$broj00);
$broj02 = implode('',$broj01);
```

Then i have problem, its work only if $broj is only one data but i can have in $broj = '09846646646,098956565,0989898' like 3 number in date.

How i can explode all that 3 number like one ? And search database for that number for name and return name?

Full code working with $broj = '0986464646'; -> only one number.

```
function realbroj_ul($broj){
    global $database;
    global $session;
    $result = "";
    //uklanjanje odredenog djela iz broja
    $broj00 = preg_replace('/'.ULAZNI_POZIV.'/', '', $broj);
    //dodavanje prefixa za ljepsi pregeld broja
    $prefix = 0;
    $broj01 = array($prefix,$broj00);
    $broj02 = implode('',$broj01);
    if ($broj02 != ''){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM imenik WHERE broj='$broj02'";
        $query = $database->query($sql);
        $row = $database->fetch_array($query);
        if ($row['id'] != ''){
            $ime = $row['ime'];
            $prezime = $row['prezime'];
            $arry = array($ime,$prezime);
            $fime = implode(" ", $arry);
            $result = "<a style='color:green;' href='index.php?stranica=imenik&korisnik=".$broj02."'>".$fime." (".$broj02.")<i class='material-icons' style='margin-top: -2px;position: absolute;color: green;margin-left: 5px;'>search</i></a>";

        }else{
            $result = "".$broj02." <a href='index.php?stranica=imenik-add&broj=".$broj02."' alt='Dodaj u imenik'><i class='material-icons' style='margin-top: -4px;position: absolute;color: blue;margin-left: 5px;'>add_circle</i>";
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Why? Some explanation?

Comment: Your database structure is  not good. But to solve this issue, save the numbers by comma separated values. Example(4324324234,4234234,). Then parse as array, exploded and use php strpos function to match the number

Comment: exploding is quite simple: $numbers = explode(",", $phone_numbers);

Search is very hard to perform on a db with this scheme. You have to move each phone number in a separate record

Comment: Try to echo the query and run it directly into mysql, Do you get the correct answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, the explode is quite simple:

```
$numbers = explode(",", $phone_numbers);
```

will return an array of phone numbers.

But you have to create a new database schema. I would advice you to create a table for clients and a table for the phone numbers. 
So you can have each phone number related with a client id. 
Searching this way you will have no problem at all.

Client Table:
ID_client | Name | Surname | etcetera

Phone Table:
ID_phone | ID_client | phone_number | type(home office, etc)